# What is the overall O(n) time complexity of O(sum(a)) if a is an array of integers and n is the length of the array?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I’m having a hard time using O(n) principles to generalize the time complexity of an algorithm whose more specific time complexity is O(sum(a)) where a is an array of integers.

My intuition is that this time complexity should generalize to O(n) as you can think of this as a “linear” equation of ki values that occur n times where k is the integer value in the array, making it O(n)( k=1 for a straight up O(n) case).

But it doesn’t seem to be exactly the same as O(n) - the value of k could be much larger than n, and if all these k values are larger you have something that could be O(n^2) or O(n^3) depending on how large that value is.

Is this something to take into account for O(n) complexity where n is the length of the array? Should I actually be defining n as the sum of all elements in the array instead of the length of the array?

In general, what would be the best way to think about this?

Comment: have you read the definition of big-oh notation?

Comment: Yes, of course. But I’m obviously misunderstanding, misinterpreting, or missing something - hence why I’m asking here.

Comment: the value of K doesn't play a role in calculating complexity (of course if it does NOT depend on the value of "n")

Comment: You would however need to consider K in a real-world problem - it may happen that O(n) algorithm runs slower than, say, O(n^2) for small values of "n". That happens due to the larger value of K for O(n) algorithm

Comment: I see, thanks makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, we want to describe the runtime of an algorithm based on the input. The "runtime" is a vague term, that is often swept under the rug. For example, the "runtime" of a sorting algorithm or a hashtable operation is measured in number of comparisons, but using "runtime" to mean the number of basic operations (which are also usually only vaguely defined) is also possible.

There are two choices (or simplifications) often made when calcuating runtime. The first, is to ignore the actual input, and to use the size of the input (measured somehow) instead. This size is usually denoted `n`. The second, is to use big-O notation to describe the worst case (or best case, or average, or amortized...).

Neither of these choices is always necessary, and sometimes, they won't make sense. To repeat, since this is the crux of the answer: describing runtimes in big-O of `n` is not the only way to describe runtimes and sometimes it makes no sense to do so.

For example, in the case of an algorithm that runs in `O(sum(a))` time:

```
func f(a) {
   t = 0
   for x in a {
      for i = 1..x {
         t += 1
      }
   }
}
```

It's not useful to describe the runtime of this using the length of the input array `a`. It's not useful because the length of `a` doesn't say anything about the worst-case runtime.

Saying that `t` is incremented `sum(a)` times *is* a useful statement about the runtime of the program. It doesn't use big-O complexity notation.

And if you *do* want to express that in big-O notation, you can say that the runtime of this code is `O(sum(a))`. This blurs exactly what you're measuring in the runtime, because you can be including the cost of performing the statements other than incrementing `t`.

And going back to the example, you *could* (and if you were studying complexity classes, you probably *would*) say `n` is the size (in bits) of the input array. Then you could say something about the runtime (measured in basic operations): it's O(2^n), since the worst case input is an array with one element which takes the value 2^n-1 (*note).

*note: this ignores some technical details about how to encode an array using bits.